# How to enable quick fix in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How to enable quick fix while hover over error in eclipse?
Currently it looks like this, so I can't import by using this popup
[image]

So, I want it to be like this:

[image]

I already restarted few times my eclipse, also I followed instructions how to check: Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced
But nothing helped...
So, the point is how to enable quick fix just by hovering over the error, I don-t want't to use Ctrl+1 or  Edit > Quick Fix every time.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse IDE are you using? I can import a class by hovering the error in both Photon and 2019-09 (Java & DSL Developers package).

Comment: Moreover, if your point is about using the mouse rather than the keyboard you can also click on the error marker (on the left side of the editor) to activate the Quick Fix popup, see https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_Quick_Fix%3F

Answer (score 2):

I am a beginner so I don't know whether it might help or not

I had the similar problem
I wanted to see the quick fix available when the cursor is on the error(red line)
(underlined blue words so that I can click and quickly fix or change what is necessary)

The problem was the something I installed from eclipse marketplace("dark theme devStyle")
I didn't know how to change the background color and I thought I needed that dark theme devStyle to change color. So I simply unintalled it and the problem solved. Also I deleted the metadata folder in the workspace to make a default setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after installing Dark theme devstyle from eclipse market place.

The solution for me was to power off my PC and turn it back on again and It worked.